# Display/Print an Array of Nested JSON API data (list) in HTML page using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I have just started working on the jQuery,javaScript and AJAX and trying to consume an API designed by me. The result at the backend is as follows

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "choice_text": "They work on List View generally",
        "poll": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "choice_text": "Learn on Digital Ocean",
        "poll": 2
    }
]
```

This is a list of Choices with id,poll id and Choice Text. I want to display this data in the HTML page using the AJAX/javaScript/jQuery. Any would do. This can Either be a **table**,**list** or **div** element. How can I do this??

When I used the below code,

```
$('#get-list').click(function () {
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-api/choices/", function (data,status) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function () {
               $('div').html('<p>'+data+'</p>')
            })
            })
        })
```

I got

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

in my page but the `console.log()` shows the Array with the objects inside it with proper format.

How can This be done? Any Idea? Have checked a few links from stackoverflow but it's going over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('div').html('<p>' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</p>')
```

but i would suggest .append() rather than .html()

Comment: Thanks . Will try it but what if I want to show it  in a table?

Comment: @Deshwal I have no idea how your table looks like but if you let me give you a example then
`$('table').append('<tr><td>'+data.id+'</td><td>'+data.choice_text+'</td><td>'+data.poll+'</td></tr>')`
will be okay if you have a table element in there

Comment: sure. Thank you.That'd do IMO